# Scripting on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I am trying to create a script that will run a program on each file in a list.  I have been trying to do this using a .csh file (I have no clue if this is the best way), and I started with something as simple as hello world

```
echo "hello world"
```

The problem is that I cannot execute this script, or verify that it works correctly.  (I was trying to do ./testscript.csh which is obviously wrong).  I haven't been able to find anything that really explains how to run C Scripts, and I'm guessing there's a better way to do this too. What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mark it as executable; Unix doesn't execute things arbitrarily based on extension.

```
chmod +x testscript.csh
```

Also, I *strongly* recommend [using `sh` or `bash` instead of `csh`](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), or you will soon learn about the idiosyncrasies of `csh`'s looping and control flow constructs (some things only work inside them if done a particular way, in particular with the single-line versions things are *very* limited).

Comment: `chmod` works, but only because the file is *also* a valid Bourne shell script.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use ./testscript.csh. You will however need to make it executable first:

```
chmod u+x testscript.csh
```

Which means set testscript to have execute permissions for the user (who ever the file is owned by - which in this case should be yourself!)

Also to tell the OS that this is a csh script you will need put

```
 #! /path/to/csh
```

on the first line (where `/path/to/csh` is the full path to csh on your system. You can find that out by issuing the command `which csh`).

That should give you the behvaiour you want.

**EDIT** As discussed in some of the comments, you may want to choose an alternative shell to C Shell (csh). It is not the friendliest one for scripting.

Comment: +1. BTW this `#!` is called a shebang - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

You can run the script from within your current shell.  If you're running csh or tcsh, the syntax is `source testscript.csh`.  If you're running sh, bash, ksh, etc., the syntax is `. ./testscript.sh`.  Note that I've changed the file name suffix; `source` or `.` runs the commands in the named file in your current shell.  If you have any shell-specific syntax, this won't work unless your interactive shell matches the one used by the script.  If the script is *very* simple (just a sequence of simple commands), that might not matter.

You can make the script an executable program.  (I'm going to repeat some of what others have already written.)  Add a "shebang" as the first line.  For a csh script, use `#!/bin/csh -f`.  The `-f` avoids running commands in your own personal startup scripts (.cshrc et al), which saves time and makes it more likely that others will be able to use it.  Or, for a sh script (recommended), used `#!/bin/sh` (no `-f`, it has a completely different meaning).  In either case, run `chmod +x the_script`, then `./the_script`.

There's a trick I often use when I want to perform some moderately complex action.  Say I want to delete some, but not all, files in the current directory, but the criterion can't be expressed conveniently in a single command.  I might run `ls > tmp.sh`, then edit tmp.h with my favorite editor (mine happens to be vim).  Then I go through the list of files and delete all the ones that I want to leave alone.  Once I've done that, I can replace each file name with a command to remove it; in vim, `:%s/.*/rm -f &/`.  I add a `#!/bin/sh` at the top save it, `chmod +x foo.sh`, then `./foo.sh`.  (If some of the file names might have special characters, I can use `:%s/.*/rm -f '&'/`.)